# create a new packet similar to that of RREQ in AODV routing protocol

Tags: routes, protocols, ns2

I want to add a new packet in aodv routingprotocol similar to that of RREQ packet.How can I do that?
I tried by adding a new packet type(npack) by changing the name of RREQ in aodv_packet.h. I also added sendnpack and recvnpack in aodv.cc, similar to that of sendRequest and recvRequest. All the other packets are processed in aodv.cc except the newly created packet.
Can anyone please help me how to get and proceed? Thanks in advance.